# how to have envs for different lambdas and integrate with API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is there any way to have envs in lambda and then connect different stages of API Gateway to different lambdas. I know one way which is using lambda versions, but the problem with that is it once published, version cant be changed, I am using CICD to deploy my lambda, so I will have to manually change the version in API gateway at each lambda deployment?
Problem I am facing using versions of lambda is that I cant update the code of the same version. How can I do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would not update a specific lambda version (which is not possible) instead you can use [API Gateway Stage Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html) to fulfil your requirement.

That means you create a new stage variable pointing at a new created version of your lambda code. If you want to update code you need to create a new stage variable and hence a new lambda version or point to a different version.

Comment: This is one solution but then I will have to manually update the version through the stage variable since each new version will have a new version number. Right? I am deploying lambdas using codedeploy for CICD, I want to make this automated